# CoreData Saving without Saving Context

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I am having some trouble with CoreData. before using the entity I delete them from Coredata, and print them out to make sure they're actually deleted. After the for loop I print them out again and they have been saved even though I have not saved the context. And when I kill the app and reload, the data is there, even though I never saved context, what is going on?

```
DataController.shared.deleteAllModifiersFromCD()
                DataController.shared.printExercisesAndModifiersFromCD()
                for mod in modSnap {
                    let modifierType = mod.childSnapshot(forPath: "type").value as! String
                    let modifier = Modifier(context: self.DC.context)
                    modifier.id = mod.key
                    modifier.modType = modifierType
                }
                DataController.shared.printExercisesAndModifiersFromCD()
```

Answer (score 0):

> when I kill the app and reload, the data is there, even though I never saved context

That is why, IIRC, when you save the context is when you actually persist the changes on disk, before that, everything happens on memory.

That is why the save context happens on `AppDelegate.applicationWillTerminate`, which is executed right before killing the app. Notice that killing the app is when you swipe up from the app switcher and not when you stop the execution from Xcode.

Comment: I am a bit confused, what you are saying is, when you delete your entities, are they still saved? before calling saveContext?